# C#: Unable to read data from the transport connection when reading from a NetworkStream for the second time?

Tags: c#

I have two simple classes, a NetworkListener and NetworkClient. Upon reading from a TcpClient's network stream that I pass into NetworkClient, I was given the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

I just don't understand this because the client did not abort the connection, and it only happens on the second iteration. Is there something I'm missing here, or something weird going on with my code?

I just don't know what steps to take next in debugging this...

The line it errors on is,

```
var bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Below I have put the full code of both the two classes.

NetworkListener:

```
public class NetworkListener : INetworkListener
{
    private readonly INetworkClientRepository _clientRepository;
    private readonly INetworkClientFactory _clientFactory;
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;

    public NetworkListener(IPEndPoint endPoint, INetworkClientRepository clientRepository, INetworkClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientRepository = clientRepository;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _listener = new TcpListener(endPoint.Address, endPoint.Port);
    }

    public void Start(int backlog = 100)
    {
        _listener.Start(backlog);
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await AcceptClient(await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
        }
    }
    
    private async Task AcceptClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            var networkClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient(client);
            _clientRepository.AddClient(networkClient);
        
            await networkClient.ListenAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

NetworkClient:

```
public class NetworkClient : INetworkClient
{
    private readonly TcpClient _tcpClient;
    private readonly INetworkPacketHandler _packetHandler;
    private readonly NetworkStream _networkStream;

    public NetworkClient(TcpClient tcpClient, INetworkPacketHandler packetHandler)
    {
        _tcpClient = tcpClient;
        _packetHandler = packetHandler;
        _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
    }
    
    public async Task ListenAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var byteArray = GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream();

            using var br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(byteArray));

            if (br.BaseStream.Length < Constants.PacketMinLength)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var messageLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(br.ReadBytes(4));
            var packetData = br.ReadBytes(messageLength);

            using var br2 = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(packetData));
            var packetId = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16BigEndian(br2.ReadBytes(2));

            await _packetHandler.HandleAsync(this, new NetworkPacket(packetId, packetData));
        }
    }

    private byte[] GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[2048];
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    public async Task WriteToStreamAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        await _networkStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: By 'the client didn't abort the connection,' do you mean your `NetworkClient` class or the thing sending you data?

Comment: Hi @CollinDauphinee I'm refering to the TcpClient or the tcpClient.GetStream() (Network Stream) belonging to the TcpClient.

Comment: I have updated my question with the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading; in this case, it can actually mean that the other end of the connection closed the socket, not your application.

My suspicion would be that the client connecting to your server is sending some data and then closing the connection.